# ASP.NET Core SignalR returns 401 Unauthorized using Azure AD

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, signalr

I have a SPA (angular 7) and an API (.Net Core) which I authenticate with Azure AD. I'm using [adal-angular4](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4) to integrate my angular application with AAD.

Everything works great, but I'm also using SignalR with the API as server and when I try to connect from my SPA I get 401 Unauthorized on the negotiate "request" and I get this back in the Response Headers:

[image: Response Header]

The request contains my Bearer token in the Authorization header, and when I run the token through [jwt.io](https://jtw.io), I can see that the "aud" value is the Azure AD ClientId for my SPA.

All regular request to the API contains the same token and I have no issues with those. I have [Authorize] on all my Controllers and on my Hub, but it's only the SignalR Hub that causes this issue.

My server Startup:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    _env = env;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
private IHostingEnvironment _env;
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    StartupHandler.SetupDbContext(services, Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevDb"));


    // Setup Authentication
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options);


        });

    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
    services.AddOptions();

    // Add AzureAD object so it can be injected
    services.Configure<AzureAdConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

    services.AddSignalR(options =>
    {
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    //app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        builder.AllowCredentials();
    });


    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseSignalR(routes => routes.MapHub<MainHub>("/mainhub"));

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Files")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Files")
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

My SignalR Hub:

```
[Authorize]
public class MainHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IEntityDbContext _ctx;

    public MainHub(IEntityDbContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        _signalRService = signalRService;
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

And this is my SignalRService on my angular client. I'm running startConnection() in the constructor of app.component.ts.

```
export class SignalRService {
    private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

    constructor(private adal: AdalService) {}

    startConnection(): void {
        this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(AppConstants.SignalRUrl, { accessTokenFactory: () => this.adal.userInfo.token})
            .build();

        this.hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 60000;

        this.hubConnection.on('userConnected', (user) => 
        {
            console.log(user);
        });

        this.hubConnection.start()
            .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
            .catch(err => 
            {
                console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err);
            });
    }
}
```

I have tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2) solution, but I can't get that to work either.

**Edit**

When I've implemented the solution from the official docs, the API stops working on regular requests as well and I get back:

[image: Signature key was not found]

I've populate the `IssuerSigningKey` property in `TokenValidationParameters` with `new SymmetricSecurityKey(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());`. Am I doing anything wrong here?

**/EDIT**

Why won't SignalR accept my accesstoken when the API otherwise accept it?

Comment: if using `AddAzureADBearer` by setting correct Instance and domain  And if using `AddJwtBearer` add `options.Authority =  https://login.microsoftonline.com/Yourtenant` , delete ` IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKey`

Comment: I tried adding options.Authority and removed IssuerSigningKey, But I got an InvalidOperationException: InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. But the Event OnMessageRecieved gets executed now, so it's a step forward.

Comment: Add `/` to endpoint , and confirm that : `options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/"` , also any detail exception message ?

Comment: It worked, thank you! Add your solution as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ok, i will also explain a bit about that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When validating the signature of access token , you should get the public key since Azure AD may sign token using any one of a certain set of public-private key pairs , the keys could be found at :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Within the JSON response, you’ll see a property `jwks_uri` which is the URI that contains the JSON Web Key Set for Azure AD. Matching the `kid` claim in jwt token , you can find the key which AAD used to sign the token with asymmetric encryption algorithms, such as RSA 256 by default .

In asp.net core apis , when validating the access token which issued by Azure AD , you can use `AddJwtBearer` extension and provide the correct `Authority` , so that middleware will correctly get the keys from Azure AD OpenID configuration endpoint :

```
options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/"
```

Another choice is to use `AddAzureADBearer` extension from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` library . You should also set correct `authority(instance + domain)` , middleware will help validating the signature and claims  based on your configuration .

Answer (score 4):

Just have a look at the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2). You need a special handling for the JWT Bearer events so your authentication is working. The token needs to be forwarded to the hubs.
Have a look at the part where I said

> THAT PART IS MISSING

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // Identity made Cookie authentication the default.
            // However, we want JWT Bearer Auth to be the default.
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            // Configure JWT Bearer Auth to expect our security key
            options.TokenValidationParameters =
                new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    LifetimeValidator = (before, expires, token, param) =>
                    {
                        return expires > DateTime.UtcNow;
                    },
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateActor = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKey
                };

            //THAT IS THE PART WHICH IS MISSING IN YOUR CONFIG !
            // We have to hook the OnMessageReceived event in order to
            // allow the JWT authentication handler to read the access
            // token from the query string when a WebSocket or 
            // Server-Sent Events request comes in.
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                    // If the request is for our hub...
                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                        (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs/chat")))
                    {
                        // Read the token out of the query string
                        context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddSignalR();

    // Change to use Name as the user identifier for SignalR
    // WARNING: This requires that the source of your JWT token 
    // ensures that the Name claim is unique!
    // If the Name claim isn't unique, users could receive messages 
    // intended for a different user!
    services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();

    // Change to use email as the user identifier for SignalR
    // services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, EmailBasedUserIdProvider>();

    // WARNING: use *either* the NameUserIdProvider *or* the 
    // EmailBasedUserIdProvider, but do not use both. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. As I said, I've tried this solution but when I use .AddJwtBearer() instead of .AddAzureADBearer(), the API stops working at all and gives me 401 on everything with the message: "The signature key was not found". I guess this has to do with the TokenValidationParameters IssuerSigningKey. I use new SymmetricSecurityKey(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray())

Comment: Okay. I was wondering because the place I marked for you in the docs is missing in your code. That allows the JWT authentication handler to read the access token. Without that it is clear that you get an 401 error.
Im pretty sure that will fix the problem.

Comment: I know, AddAzureADBearer() doesn't have Events so I don't know where I would implement that without changing to AddJwtBearer(), and I can't get that to work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Change the Authorize attribute on your hub to

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Comment: I've tried this, but there's no change I'm afraid. I've also tried using [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AzureADBearer")] without success

Comment: Actually I just noticed that you do not configure the app to use authorization in your startup class:

app.UseAuthorization();

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure

This is how I have my blazor SPA setup:

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });